# Is it possible to use a private laptop's keyboard for an intranet desktop computer?

Tags: keyboard

I have physical access to a desktop (CentOS) which is **connected to a closed, protected and restricted intranet**.  I use at the same time my Funtoo-Linux based laptop.

The organisation's policy does not allow me, however, to access the desktop from any kind of external media. That means that I have no rights (at least, not yet) to access the desktop via ssh.

I can use external media directly on the desktop, such as USB keys and external storage. But that's about it.

Is there any way that will enable me to use my laptop's keyboard, instead of the desktop's external keyboard, to work also in the desktop, whenever I am physically present in the office where the desktop is installed?

Or, are there alternatives to just use only one keyboard (via a bluetooth adapter for example)?

Comment: Niko, could you please [edit] your question and explain what you need that a simple `ssh` doesn't provide? I assume this "closed, protected and restricted intranet" means you can't ssh in, right? If so, please mention that explicitly to avoid confusion.

Comment: It very much depends what you are allowed to do on the restricted laptop. Could you use a USB keyboard? A USB Ethernet adapter? A USB modem? Do you have network access? Etc. If the Laptop is properly locked down in the interest of security, you probably can't do any of those things.

Comment: @dirkt the laptop is my own linux box. No restrictions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the restricted *desktop*. (The laptop is of course unrestricted.)

Answer (score 0):

You could SSH in, but I assume that's not what you want.

I'd recommend checking out [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/) - it's a keyboard and mouse sharing software which works on most *nix boxes, Windows and Mac

If you'd prefer a free version they offer, it's [here](http://symless.com/download-synergy-for-free?adwords=free-download-3&gclid=CPeLy9m5j9ICFRUTGwodyPMDhA), but bear in mind it's unsupported.

You would need to set the machine you want to use the keyboard of as the server, and the centos box as the client.

Comment: I have used Synergy in the past. But can't connect to the intranet. And, naturally, I can't ssh to it. I don't want even to attempt to do that. But I have the desktop right in my working place.

Comment: is the desktop not on the same lan as your work laptop if it's in the same office?   If not, it must have some sort of network connectivity for it to be able to be on your intranet. 

how do you access the intranet from your laptop? If you have to VPN in somewhere, then you could use synergy over the VPN. If it's a local IP you use to access the intranet, there should be no problem using synergy as it is.

Comment: No, I am not on the IntraNet. Not allowed. I have access to a guest wifi. And my personal access to internet via my phone (4g). Practically I have no access to the box remotely because it's not allowed.

Comment: In which case there are two options I see:

1) use your phone as a proxy to get to the intranet via your 4g connection - though unless you have unlimited tethering, I'd avoid this

2) request access to a lan connection via ethernet, rather than using the guest wifi - then use synergy

Comment: In which case there is only (your suggested) option 1. Is this possible? How can one get into an organisation's restricted intranet via a private 4g connection?

Comment: that would depend on how you access your intranet via the phone. Does your 4G connection simply allow access to it? Or do you have to connect via a program of sorts? 

If it's just allowed by your phone's IP, then tethering directly should allow you to access it from your laptop. 

if there's a program you need to use then you may find it a bit more difficult

Comment: Apologies if I don't see the obvious here, or if my question is still not well explained. The only access from outside the organisation's _services_, that is not being physically inside the organisation, is some kind of a "log in to that, then access some extra-net wiki or a web-based outlook client for mails". That's it. There is no legal way, as far as I know, to access a desktop except of being physically in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Take it as a PoC but as usb keyboards often work out of the box you can take a look to this one arduino based: http://hackaday.com/2012/06/29/turning-an-arduino-into-a-usb-keyboard/

The next step is to use arduino as a server getting input from your laptop with a Ethernet shield.